# Two projects in ASP.NET in same folder

Tags: asp.net

When I create a subdomain or a new app in my hosting and I upload my site it works good, but I have a problem when I want to upload two app in the same domain.

I create two dir: site1, site2 and I upload every site in their folder.

But I can't run them, every site needs to be in the root of my domain to works and I can't merge this projects (different libs, web.config, etc).

Is any way to make it?
a general web.config? some config especial? or anything

BTW, i haven't access to applications pools or windows commands in my hosting.

Thanks!

Comment: If both are the same application how come that you call them site1 and site2... Give a me a sample of the URLs and how you expect how those should work

Comment: Example: Domain.com/site1 and domain.com/site2. 
If I put all project to root of domain.com works, but if I put it in site1 folder, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you need to is create inside your root folder two virtual directories.

ASP.NET is defined/started on global.asax and web.config files and configurations and you can't have 2 separate projects inside the same application. In the scenario you described, it sounds like you need to create a "Virtual Directory" in IIS for both of your applications instead of making just creating "Sub Folders".

The Virtual Directory will allow you to have 2 web.config and 2 global.asax where you set the configurations for each of your applications and this will also give you the freedom for independent updates without affecting your either project.

For a full walkthrough on how you can perform this please refer to this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx